React state change doesn't re-render
I've read a ton of posts and articles, tried different approaches, inluding useContext, useReducer, etc. but i still can't understand why state does not change and why the page is not rerendering?
const [access, setAccess] = useState(localStorage.getItem('access'));

    useEffect(() => {
        setAccess(localStorage.getItem('access'));
    }, []);

If i pass [access] to useEffect, it becomes an infinite loop. I've added the code in the parent component and passed access as an argument, still doesn't work. No surprise there are more than 30 pages with similar posts and most of the answers are unclear, outdated or not working for me. AI also failed to solve this tiny problem. I'm using funcional components, most of the info I've found i about class-based components.
Edit (clarification): I wanted to re-render the header component every time the access parameter in the localStorage changes. For example, I log in, the access changes in the localStorage, the state should listen for this change, the diplayed data in the header should change as well, I log out - the localStorage changes, the state should listen for this change and header should change as well. I tried several times with the window.addEventListener method, but nothing changed. The state does not listen for changes in the localStorage, BUT when i resresh the page, the state magically changes.
This is the structure of my App.jsx (was initially outside ):
https://github.com/xaoccc/Tasks/blob/main/frontend/src/App.jsx
In components dir you can see that now i have 2 headers - for logged in users and for the other ones, as I couldn't manage the state update which should be here:
https://github.com/xaoccc/Tasks/blob/main/frontend/src/components/Header.jsx
Here is a previous version of the header (state not updating, again):
https://github.com/xaoccc/Tasks/blob/d50118b6e615245a05c3e6705546c32ad8f58fb4/frontend/src/components/Header.jsx

It's because, nothing changes. State 'access'  is not changed, so there is no need in rerendering.

And it's depends what you want to achieve. May be you want react to listen, when localstorage is changing. If yes, there is another way to do that. just with wrintig in useEffect localStorage.getItem, react will not understand, that he shoud change, when it's changed

Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you are trying to do here? You are enqueueing a state update to the same current state value, so it's very well likely React isn't going to waste time/resources rerendering when the result won't actually be different.

@DrewReese, I wanted to re-render the header component every time the access changes, not onClick. For example, i log in, the access changes in the local storage, the diplayed data in the header should change as well, I log out - the local storage changes, the state should listen for this change and header should change as well.

LocalStorage is non-reactive, meaning, it's not going to trigger React to rerender and update its local state. You basically have it exactly backwards, i.e. when a user logs in or out you should update the state (to trigger the component rerender) and then persist the state out to localStorage.

Hi, Probably this answer would address this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78973915/vanilla-react-navbar-non-reactive-upon-updating-local-storage

The reason your React component isn’t re-rendering when you update localStorage is that React doesn’t automatically track changes to localStorage. It only re-renders when the component's state changes via useState or setState, and differs from the current value.
When you do:
const [access, setAccess] = useState(localStorage.getItem('access'));

React grabs the initial value from localStorage, but it won’t re-render unless you call setAccess() with a new value.
If you want the component to update when localStorage changes, you can listen to the storage event like this:
useEffect(() => {
  const handleStorageChange = () => {
    setAccess(localStorage.getItem('access'));
  };

  window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
}, []);

However, this doesn’t fire for changes in the same tab, so after updating localStorage, you’ll need to manually update the state:
localStorage.setItem('access', 'newValue');
setAccess('newValue'); // This triggers the re-render

So all in all it should look like this
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [access, setAccess] = useState(localStorage.getItem('access')); 

  useEffect(() => {

    const handleStorageChange = () => {
      setAccess(localStorage.getItem('access'));
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const updateAccess = (newValue) => {
    localStorage.setItem('access', newValue);
    setAccess(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Access Value: {access ? access : 'No Access'}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => updateAccess('newAccessValue')}>
        Update Access
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

Let me know if this helps!

I wanted to re-render the header component every time the access changes, not onClick. For example, i log in, the access changes in the local storage, the diplayed data in the header should change as well, I log out - the state changes, the header should change as well. Thank you for your code and clear explanation, I tested it with a button, but still - I log in, the state should be changed, I click the button and there is no change at all. I solved my problem with creating two header components. useState rarely works for me, because of its unpredictable behavior.

Glad you sorted it out, if you're not satisfied with your solution, feel free to share a code-pen.

@NikoiNikoi "useState rarely works for me, because of its unpredictable behavior." - What?! It's completely predictable behavior.

You made a mistake using useEffect. In function components, useEffect works like componentDidMount or componentWillMount in class components. This is, the code inside useEffect is executed when the dependencies of useEffect change.
But in your code, you don't have any dependency so the useEffect will be executed like componentDidMount, in order words, it will be only once excuted once function component is mounted.
In this caes, if you set initial state value of accces to null or an empty string, the page will be rendered, but since you already set initial state value of access to localStorage.getItem('access'), even if you try to setAccess(localStroage.getItem('access') inside useEffect, the page will not rerender.
Therefore, if you want to re-render the page based on changing the access value of localStroage, you need to listen the localStroage change event in useEffect and set the value to access to trigger rerender.
Below is the sample code:
const MyFunctionComponent = () => {
    const [access, setAccess] = useState(localStorage.getItem('access'))

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleStorageChange = () => {
            const updatedValue = localStorage.getItem('access');
            setAccess(updatedValue);
        };

        window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageChange);

        return () => {
            widow.removeEventListener('storage', onStorageChange);
        };
    }, [])
    
    return (
        // Please put your component content
    );
}

export default MyFunctionComponent;

Note: you should use a cleanup function in useEffect to avoid potential mistakes in the future.

This is literally the same solution as the first one. Even the AI suggested me this solution yesterday. I tested it and it doesn't work.

Hmm... I don't understand well. I tried to explain correct workflow of useEffect. Please provide me your full code so that I can find what's wrong.
