Vanilla React Navbar non-reactive upon updating local storage
I have this react App structure. Some components are hidden based on the content of a local storage.
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRoutes from "./Routes";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <AppRoutes />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;

All of my other react components are responsive except Navbar. What am I doing wrong? This is my NavBar code:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function NavBar() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setRole(localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole"));
  }, []);
    return (
        <header className="bg-white">
            <nav className="" aria-label="Global">
                {/* Links (Center-aligned) */}
                <div className="">
                    {role==='a' && <a href="/events" className="">a</a>}
                    {role==='b' && <a href="/events" className="">EveBnts</a>}
                </div>

            </nav>
        </header>
    );
}

export default NavBar;

The problem is, I have to refresh the page to see the changes take effect. How do I solve this issue?

Your useEffect dependency array is empty, so the hook will only run when the NavBar first renders (or after a refresh, of course).
The naive solution is to just add localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole") to the dependency array. It will work, but it will throw a warning because React does not want a complex function in the array since that's very expensive to track changes on, unlike a variable.
The more complex solution is to create an event listener on the window and update your state that way. You can bundle that logic in a custom hook. I'll include Maxim's answer here from another question:

You can use custom hooks for that
const profile = useProfileData();

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function getProfileData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
}

export default function useProfileData() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(getProfileData());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleChangeStorage() {
      setProfile(getProfileData());
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleChangeStorage);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', handleChangeStorage);
  }, []);

  return profile;
}

if you don't get why it's not catched see that question Storage event not firing
in summary it's catching events on different pages


Hi, I have tried both of these methods previously. It still does not work. It does not even trigger the window.addEventListener('storage', handleChangeStorage); even if I console.log it.

Have you read vsync's answer linked by Maxim? The storage event will only natively trigger from changes made in another tab. To force it to trigger on your current tab, you can manually throw the 'storage' event when you change the value.

Yes I have. The weird thing is that I can run role === "null" ? "hidden" : "" but I cannot run role === "a" ? "hidden" : "". I already use return JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole")); to cast it into string

So turns out this works. However, JSON.stringify returns results with quotes involved e.g, "result" and not simply result. so I use this as the get function's return instead: return JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole")).replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '$1');

If you know the value of the localStorage item is going to just be a string, then I think you can avoid the JSON.stringify altogether and just return the getItem to strip the quote characters automatically, but if your regex solution works, then that's great! Glad it's working.

Weirdly enough, I tried without stringify and it wont work for some reason. It breaks the conditionals. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Can you see if at all there is any thing being stored in local storage in the first place?
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function NavBar() {
const [role, setRole] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
const storedRole = localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole");
if (storedRole) {
  setRole(storedRole);
} else {
  setRole("");
}
}, []);

return (
<header className="bg-white">
  <nav aria-label="Global">
    {/* Links (Center-aligned) */}
    <div>
      {role === 'a' && <a href="/events" className="">a</a>}
      {role === 'b' && <a href="/events" className="">EveBnts</a>}
    </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 );
 }

export default NavBar;


I inspected using chrome devtool in "Application"->"Local Storage" and the value is there, It just does not change without me having to refresh it. I even tried displaying {role}, which shows null, and then "a" after I trigger the local storage change...

Were you able to console log and see the local storage item in your useEffect ?

Yep, I got the console log. Event {isTrusted: false, type: 'storage', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}

The weird thing is that I can run role === "null" ? "hidden" : "" but I cannot run role === "a" ? "hidden" : "". I already use return JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("tempUserRole")); to cast it into string
